# MongoDB text search doesn't search single word

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I want to search through my blogs collection in my MongoDB database. I want to search by title, I create the index with mongoose in the schema's file. Everything is cool but if I for example have a blog with a title like this: "averylongtitlewithoutspaces", it won't search it unless I type in the whole title. It's works okay with spaces so searching "a very" returns "a very long title with spaces". How can I make mongo search the text with spaces?.

Here's my schema file

```js
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

interface IBlog {
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: String,
    authorId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    shortContent: String,
    image: String
}


const BlogSchema = new Schema<IBlog>({
    title: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    content: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    authorId: {
        required: true,
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Account"
    },
    shortContent: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    image: {
        requred: true,
        type: String
    }


}, { 
    timestamps: true
}); 
BlogSchema.index({ title: "text" }, {default_language: "none"});


export const Blog = model("Blog", BlogSchema, "blogs");
```

Query that I'm making:

```js
    const blogs = await Blog.find({ $text: { $search: req.params.input } });
```

Comment: Please add a query that you are making.

Comment: @Ayzrian added, sorry about that I completely forgot.

Comment: You can search with regular expressions like {name:/.*sam.*/}

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes to your query. For example:

```
{"$text":{"$search":"\"hello world\""}}
```

Note that you can't use a regex for text fields/indexes.

(If you're working with web content, make sure to look out for %20s...)